# How to change the innerHTML of the DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi I have two functions in js which is replacing the property of the DOM, having either "Practitioner" or "Patient"  but it is going inside the loop and condition but not getting changed.

```
function ReplaceInnerHtml(el, type, replaceTo) {
  if (el != "" && el != null) {
    if (type == "Practitioner") {
      el.innerHTML.replace("Practitioner", replaceTo);
    } else if (type == "Patient") {
      el.innerHTML.replace("Patient", replaceTo);
    }
  }
}

function SetAllDivLabelCaption(OABPreferences) {
  var listlabel = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
  var listspan = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  var listdiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < listlabel.length; i++) {
    if (listlabel[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Practitioner") > -1) {
      ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listlabel[i].id), "Practitioner", OABPreferences.OABRenamePractitioner);
    } else if (listlabel[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Patient") > -1) {
      ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listlabel[i].id), "Patient", OABPreferences.OABRenamePatient);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < listspan.length; i++) {
    if (listspan[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Practitioner") > -1) {
      ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listspan[i].id), "Practitioner", OABPreferences.OABRenamePractitioner);
    } else if (listspan[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Patient") > -1) {
      ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listspan[i].id), "Patient", OABPreferences.OABRenamePatient);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < listdiv.length; i++) {
    if (listdiv[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Practitioner") > -1) {
      ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listdiv[i].id), "Practitioner", OABPreferences.OABRenamePractitioner);
    } else if (listdiv[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Patient") > -1) {
      ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listdiv[i].id), "Patient", OABPreferences.OABRenamePatient);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you create a fiddle?

Comment: Sure...I will make a fiddle

Comment: `el.innerHTML.replace("Patient", replaceTo)` returns the modified string, it does not set anything. You need to assign the returned string to the property to set it to the new value, so…………… `el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace("Patient", replaceTo)`

Comment: Do not create a fiddle, post code here as a runnable snippet, reduce the code to a [*minimal example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have done the changes

Comment: and your comment works thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ReplaceInnerHtml(el, type, replaceTo) {
                if (el != "" && el != null) {
                    if (type == "Practitioner") {

                        el.innerHTML=el.innerHTML.replace("Practitioner", replaceTo);
                    }
                    else if (type == "Patient") {
                       el.innerHTML= el.innerHTML.replace("Patient", replaceTo);
                    }
                }


            }
            function SetAllDivLabelCaption() {
                var listlabel = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
                var listspan = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
                var listdiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
                for (var i = 0; i < listlabel.length; i++) {
                    if (listlabel[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Practitioner") > -1) {
                        ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listlabel[i].id), "Practitioner", "ROB");
                    }
                    else if (listlabel[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Patient") > -1) {
                        ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listlabel[i].id), "Patient", "BOB");
                    }
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < listspan.length; i++) {
                    if (listspan[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Practitioner") > -1) {
                        ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listspan[i].id), "Practitioner", "ROB");
                    }
                    else if (listspan[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Patient") > -1) {
                        ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listspan[i].id), "Patient", "BOB");
                    }
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < listdiv.length; i++) {
                    if (listdiv[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Practitioner") > -1) {
                        ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listdiv[i].id), "Practitioner", "ROB");
                    }
                    else if (listdiv[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Patient") > -1) {
                        ReplaceInnerHtml(document.getElementById(listdiv[i].id), "Patient", "BOB");
                    }
                }
            }
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Javascript example no.2</h1>
<label id="lbl1">Label-Practitioner</label><br/>
<label id="lbl2">Label-Again Prac Pat</label><br/>
<label id="lbl3">Label-Patient</label><br/>
<span id="spn1">Span-Practitioner</span><br/>
<span id="spn2">Span-Again Practitioner</span><br/>
<span id="spn3">Span-No Prac</span><br/>
<div id="dv1">Div-Practitioner</div><br/>
<div id="dv2">Div-Again Practitioner</div><br/>
<div id="dv3">Div-No Prac</div><br/>
<button onclick="SetAllDivLabelCaption();">
Replace
</button>
```

On Basis of @RobG comments I added the answer of the question as it is working after adding `el.innerHTML=el.innerHTML.replace("Practitioner", replaceTo);`
Thanks for the help.Thanks @RobG